# Convert a json file (json array) to a list of complex objects with a map as one of the properties

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a class (let's call it Data) which is defined as follows:

```
private String id;
private String eventId;
private int aggrInterval;
@JsonProperty("map")
private Map<String, Double[]> dataseries;
```

I also have a json file that looks like this:

```
[{"eventId":"a","id":"ce6","aggrInterval":5,"dataseries":{"vol":[252.0,243.0],"speed":[50.0,51.0]}},{...}, {...}]
```

Now, I'd like to extract all objects from the file and save them in a list that contains `Data` objects. I did the following but it doesn't work:

```
List<Data> dataFromFile = new ObjectMapper()
                .readValue(inputStream, new TypeReference<>() {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very close to the solution; you have to delete the `@JsonProperty("map")` from your `Data` class (the *dataseries* property name is equal to the *dataseries* fieldname in your class, so *map* property name is wrong):

```
public class Data {

    private String id;
    private String eventId;
    private int aggrInterval;
    private Map<String, Double[]> dataseries;

}
```

The conversion is pretty similar to yours except that the `TypeReference` now refers to the `List<Data>` type:

```
List<Data> data = objectMapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<Data>>(){});
```

Comment: Well, it doesn't work with removed ´@JsonProperty("map")´ either. Add adding List<Data> doesn't change anything as "Explicit type argument List<Data> can be replaced with <>"

Comment: @RobertSzooba I checked again and it works fine (jackson 2.12.2).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [Jackson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core) Object Mapper like so :

```
static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
        .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
        .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(new File("path to file"));

List<Data> list = Arrays.asList(mapper.treeToValue(node, Data[].class));
```